# Check whether the given two words are existing in a PHP string

Tags: php, string

I want to check if a string contains two specific words.

For example:

I need to check if the string contains `"MAN" & "WAN"` in a sentence like `"MAN live in WAN"` and `returns true else false`.

### What I've tried is looping string function in a conditional way:-

```
<?php
    $data = array("MAN","WAN");
    $checkExists = $this->checkInSentence($data);
    function checkInSentence( $data ){
        $response = TRUE;
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            if (strpos($string, $word) === FALSE) {
               return FALSE;
            }   
        }
        return $response;
    }       
?>
```

Is it the right method or do I've to change it? How to implement this any suggestions or idea will be highly appreciated.

```
Note: data array may contain more than two words may be. I just need check whether a set of words are exists in a paragraph or sentence.
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `$this->checkInSentence` with simple function? I'm pretty sure that you should read some more about PHP. Also your code contains logical error.

Comment: `^(?=.*MAN)(?=.*WAN).*`

Comment: *"if `strpos` equals false response equals true"*...?!

Comment: @ElonThan. Can you suggest alternate methods in preg match. I'm little week in reg. expression and preg match. Also I've edited the logical part.thanks deceze

Comment: @AvinashRaj. Can you detail using that reg. expression?

Comment: @Hoja.M.A you can also find Needhi Agrawal answer for detailed regex

Comment: @RakeshSharma If I want us it for a lot of words in a large paragraph what should I do?

Comment: then post a new question and what you have tried depends on your requirement

Comment: that's what I've done through a user defined function in my for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("(".preg_quote($string1).".*?".preg_quote($string2).")s",$data,$matches);
```

Comment: Note: data array may contain more than two words may be. I just need check whether a set of words are exists in a paragraph or sentence.will it work

Comment: In my case $data is nothing but sentence or paragraph not array.

Answer (score 3):

It's alsmost good. You need to make it set the response to false if a word is not included. Right now it'll always give true.

```
if (strpos($string, $word) === FALSE) {
               $response = FALSE;
            }
```

Comment: it won't *always* return true, it'll return true of the last array item was in the string. But your answer will still work

Comment: No he already sets the value to true at the start as well, so it'll always be true.

Answer (score 1):

This also should work!

```
$count = count($data);
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (strpos($string, $value) === FALSE) {
        #$response = TRUE; // This is subject to change so not reliable
        $i++;
    }   
}
if($i<$data)
   response = FALSE;
```